# Showing $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2=\sqrt{|x-y|}$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ define equivalent metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This isn't homework, I am just trying to better understand how to show two functions define the same metric.

I would like to show that $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2=\sqrt{|x-y|}$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ define equivalent metrics. I know that if there exist positive real numbers $a,b$ such that $ad_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)\leq bd_1(x,y)$, that is sufficient to show they are equivalent, but I can't seem to find such constants.

Do constants $a$ and $b$ exist to satisfy the above inequality, or is this a case where one must look at the open balls generated by $d_1$ and $d_2$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No. $\:$ (i.e., such constants do not exist, and this is not a case where one must look at the open balls.) $\hspace{.21 in}$ One should show that both change-the-metric maps are [Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition). $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: The metrics generate the same topology but they are not equivalent metrics in the sense described above.

Comment: @copper.hat equivalent metrics means that they generate the same topology. The constants condition means they are Lipschitz equivalent which is stronger.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Thanks, I have seen various definitions, I edited my comment to clarify what I meant.

Comment: With the constants, that is often called "strongly equivalent".

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification, I am only just beginning to learn about this.

Comment: There are some good comments in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics. Also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/137783/27978.